# Can't get rid of 1px transparent line between elements in Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a container with a background video, and I am creating a slanted div effect by absolutely positioning a div with a triangular image at the bottom of the div.

The structure for the div:

```
<div class="triangle">
     <img src="triangle.png" />
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.triangle img {
  width: 100%
}
```

[image: The offending line]

It works and looks perfectly fine on Chrome, Firefox, and even IE11, but on Edge there is a one pixel transparent bleed-through of the background video no matter what I do.  I've tried shifting the image down a few pixels, giving it a higher z-index, adding, translating and positioning multiple white pseudo elements to cover it up, but Edge will not display the elements as flush or allow the line to be covered up by seemingly any means.

Does anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it?

Edit: Sorry for the absence, Thanksgiving!

Here is a link to the PNG triangle being used: https://res.cloudinary.com/dgeb3iekh/image/upload/v1542393468/new-slant_ga8nka.png

[Here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/KrqJMx) is a Codepen that reproduces the problem in Edge (for me anyway).

Comment: make the image display:block

Comment: According to your code, I can't reproduce the problem on my side, can you share the triangle.png image and all of the related code?

Comment: I've posted the image and recreated the issue in Codepen.  It's very strange!

Comment: It seems like a "classic" case of aliasing / rounding error in non 100% zoom and/or DPI factor environment - if you can't see it just try zooming in or out, you'll almost certainly hit it in any browser. You cannot do much about it, just be prepared and "overlap everything positioned".

Comment: (btw, it seems you are using quite modern CSS transforms already, I think you could get quite working slant effect just using `.parent{transform: scale(1.2) rotate(10deg);}.child{transform: scale(0.8) rotate(-10deg);}` alone…)

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately the line simply cannot be overlapped.  I've tried translating the top element down over it and giving it a high z-index, adding a white pseudoelement to position over the space, but it will bleed through quite literally anything.  I was able to give the illusion of fixing it by just putting white space at the top of the background image that was showing through, but I'll have to create the slant effect through a different method since it's repeated everywhere on the website.  Not sure if those transforms will cause problems for IE11, but I'll give them a go!